# How do I use the JavaScript file in a vue component in the context of Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JavaScript file which contains the data of a chart, I want that chart to be displayed in a Vue component, but how can I do that.

Javascript file named as `LineChart.js`

```
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    date: [
      1600934100.0,
      1602009600.0,
      1602747060.0,
      1603050158.390939,
      1603305573.992575
    ],
    challenge: [
      9.0,
      9.5,
      2.5,
      11.52,
      12.4
    ]
  }),

  mounted() {
    let data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
      x: new Date(date * 1000),
      y: this.challenge[index]
    }))

    let ctx = this.$refs.chart.getContext('2d')
    let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: 'month',
              displayFormats: {
                month: 'MMM YYYY'
              }
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return value + 'k';
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

And my Vue component named as `Test.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="To display chart">
    <vx-card>
      <div class="chart-container">
        <LineChart></LineChart>    <-- I want my chart here
      </div>
    </vx-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LineChart from './LineChart.js'
export default {
  name: 'Test'
}
</script>
```

I have two questions:

1. Nothing is displayed in my case, so I want to know how Javascript can be imported to Vue component in order to display the chart.
2. In my JavaScript file, I want to use API instead of data & challenge directly and the date from API should be converted just like the logic I have used, I just want to know how API can be used and the flow of it and conversion of timestamps of API s resource.

Comment: You have used vue api in LineChart.js. hence its vue file. should be LineChart.vue. does it have template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing some concepts, specially the "javascript file". What you are trying to do (IMO) is to attach a VueJS component (LineChart) inside another VueJS file (Test).

To do this, I recommend you to take a look at the VueJS docs about components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Then, you can use the "LineChart" as a normal VueJS component, (import it, use it within , etc.) and you should change the file extension from .js to .vue.

So, I recommend you to change the first file to a .vue file, and then, import it in the Test file by:

```
import LineChart from "@/components/LineChart.vue";
```

Also, the component will not render because you should attach the chart to some HTML element:

```
<template>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</template>
    
<script>
[...]
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); //attach to "mychart" 
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
...
</script>
```

Finally, if you want to fetch data from an API, the standard way is to do with Axios: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

And then, in the mounted cycle make the API call:

```
axios
      .get('yourAPIURL')
      .then(response => (this.data = response))
```

Also, as a recommendation, is better to ask 2 different questions if you have 2 problems.